# $(\frac{1}{3},1)\cup(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{3})\cup(\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{5})\cup\ldots$ is not a finite union of open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X=(\frac{1}{3},1)\cup(\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{3})\cup(\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{5})\cup\ldots \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

I have tried to show that $X$ is not a finite union of open intervals.

Does the following argument make sense?

---

Suppose, for contradiction, that 
$$X=(a_1,b_1)\cup\ldots\cup(a_n,b_n)$$ 
where we assume that $a_1\leq a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n.$

If $a_1<0,$ then there is a negative number in $X$ - which is a contradiction.

If $a_1=0,$ then $X$ contains $\frac{1}{2m+1}$ for sufficiently large $m \in \mathbb{N}$ - which is a contradiction.

If $a_1>0,$ then $X$ does not contain $\frac{1}{2m}$ for sufficiently large $m \in \mathbb{N}$ - which is a contradiction.

Comment: Proof looks good

Comment: Nice proof, I would add $\frac{1}{2m}\in \left(\frac{1}{2m+1},\frac{1}{2m-1}\right)$ just for clarification.

Comment: An alternate approach. 
The complement of a finite union of open sets has a finite set of path-connected components. Show that the complement of $X$ does not by finding an infinite set of points $y_1,y_2,\cdots$ such that every path from $y_i$ to $y_j$ passes through $X.$

Comment: I like the proof in the OP, but here's another proof, for the sake of variety. If $X$ is a union of $n$ intervals, then at least two of the $n+1$ numbers $\frac12,\frac14,\ldots,\frac1{2n+2},$ say $\frac1{2p},\frac1{2q}$ where $p<q,$ belong to the same interval, call it $I.$ But then $\frac1{2q-1}\in(\frac1{2q},\frac1{2p})\subseteq I\subseteq X,$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments!

Answer (score 2):

To see a stronger statement: your $X$ has infinitely many connected components, a finite union of open intervals $F$ would have finitely many. So they are not even homeomorphic to each other.