# Showing that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}(j - 1/2, j] \times (0, 1]$ cannot be expressed as a finite union

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Follow-up to [Collection of finite unions of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are an algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700392/collection-of-finite-unions-of-half-open-rectangles-in-mathbbr2-are-an-alg).

> Let $R_j = (j - 1/2, j] \times (0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider $R = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}R_j$. How do I show that $R$ cannot be expressed as a **finite union** of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - i.e., rectangles of the form $(a, b] \times (c, d]$ with $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ and $-\infty \leq c < d \leq \infty$, where we define $(a, \infty] := (a, \infty)$?

I am reviewing real analysis fundamentals, and would like to know how to approach this problem. I suppose we could approach this with a proof by contradiction: suppose $R$ could be expressed as a union of $k < \infty$ rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then there exists a bijection $f: \{1, \dots, k\} \to \{Q_1, \dots, Q_k\}$ where $Q_k$ are half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I'm not sure how I would find a contradiction beyond this.

My method might be way off, so methods that one would be expected to know **prior** to a first measure theory course would be welcome.

Comment: The definitely of $R_j$ doesn’t use the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm reusing a comment from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670129/frac13-1-cup-frac15-frac13-cup-frac17-frac15-cup-l) similar question.)

If $R$ were a finite union of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ then the projection
$$
X = \{ x : (x, y) \in R \text{ for some } y \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(n - \frac12, n\right]
$$
would be a finite union of half-open intervals in $\mathbb{R}.$

The integers $1, 2, \ldots, m + 1$ belong to $X$ for every positive integer $m.$ By the Pigeonhole Principle, if $X$ is a union of $m$ intervals, at least one of them must contain two integers $\leqslant m + 1.$ If $K$ is such an interval, then
$$
n - \frac23 \in [n - 1, n] \subseteq K \subseteq X, \text{ for some integer } n \text{ such that } 2 \leqslant n \leqslant m + 1.
$$
But this contradicts the definition of $X,$ so the hypothesis must be false.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First check that $(a,b]\times (c,d]$ is not contained in $R$ whenever one of the numbers $a,b,c, d $ is $\pm \infty$. [It helps to draw a picture. It helps to consider the points $(n-\frac 1  2, 1)$ for this].

Then  note that a finite union of sets of the form $(a,b]\times (c,d]$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ is a bounded set and $R$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every rectangle is connected.

Suppose we can write $R$ as $R = A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$, where each $A_k$ is a (possibly infinite) rectangle.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x_1$ and let
$S_n = \{ x | f(x) \in (n-{1 \over 2},n+{1 \over 4}) \}$.

Note that the $S_n$ are open and disjoint and $R \subset \cup_n S_n$.

Suppose $A_k \cap S_n$ is not empty, then we must have $A_k \subset S_n$
otherwise this would contradict connectivity of $A_k$. Hence we must
have $R \subset \cup_{n=-N}^N S_n$ for some finite $N$.

However, it is easy to check that $S_n \cap R $ is not empty for all $n$ which is a contradiction, hence we cannot write $R$ as the finite union of connected sets.